# Is there a relation between half space and Eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

I request earnestly apology if the question is not well defined. I think I  understand half space and Eigenvectors to an extent, but could not connect both of them under the same geometry or ''umbrella''. I am sure I am missing something. So is there any way to visualize them together? In other words is Eigenvector related to half space somehow?

Comment: Is there anything in particular that makes you suspect there should be a connection?

Comment: Well my understanding may be wrong, but I was expecting that each of them (eigenvectors and possible half spaces) are part of a geometric structure and it is fixed once we specify matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I think tensors are a possible connection, more specifically the Transient Green tensor.

For more general themes, you may want to take a look at the following articles. From what you have described, you would probably be really interested in Poincaré and Siegel Half planes and the geometric generalizations:

Here are some articles which hopefully answer your questions:

General Half space definition:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)#Upper_and_lower_half-spaces

Siegel Half space:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_upper_half-space

Poincaré half plane model:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_half-plane_model

And Hilbert modular space forms:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_modular_form

Comment: It is not obvious how do you say that article relates half space and Eigenvectors.

Comment: oh, these are half spaces on shapes and the tensors that are associated with them. Maybe that didn't answer your question. Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: I see, it makes sense now. But I was expecting some relation applicable in higher dimensional spaces as well. My interest is in Eigenvectors generated from positive definite matrices.

Comment: Oh, ok sure. Let me think about that. So you are looking at the upper half spaces? Also are you looking for Poincare half planes or Siegel half planes per chance? It sounds like you are looking at Siegel half planes. @Creator

Comment: I am not sure if I can specify in that terms:  if the original matrix or the operator is symmetric then it may not matter. I guess I am not clear of the problem yet.

Comment: @Creator Hopefully my edited answer will help you enhance your problem/understanding of the problem. I think this is more along the lines of what you were thinking.

Comment: Sure, I will go though and hopefully I will learn more. Truly thanks

Comment: no worries mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22638/discussion-between-creator-and-forrest-channing-hunter).